# Decimal values in textboxes

Tags: c#, regex

I need to allow only gps coordinate values in a textbox, the format will be 2 digits then a decimal point and 5 digits after the decimal. E.g. "28.98706".

How can I accomplish this? I would also appreciate if someone could explain the difference between using regex and regular expressions.

Comment: RegEx is abbreviation for Regular Expression.

Comment: Are you aware that there is another valid GPS representation with minutes, seconds, etc? (Just in case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `numericUpDown` would be better. But here is a possible solution with `TextBox`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;

   if (e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox1.Text.Length < 2) e.Handled = true;

   if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.') e.Handled = true; // check for non-digit character

   if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2 && e.KeyChar != '.') e.Handled = true; // you should type dot '.'

   if (textBox1.Text.Length == 8) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Although it looks good, you cannot swallow KeyEvent when the textbox is full. F.e. you won't be able to tab-out from the textbox's focus. I'd use TextChanged event instead and erase last digit if Text.Length exceeds 8.

Comment: @Tarec I guess with the `if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;` we can :))

Comment: Thank you all for the possible solutions! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a textbox. Use NumericUpDown instead - it stores value in decimal format, allowing you to set decimal point precision.

Also regex = regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Regex and regular expressions are the same thing. Use it to validate the user input to your pattern of allowed values.

Example:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*", TextBox.Text)) 
    return false;

return true;
```